# How to combine a blurred emit pass with rest of render?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I am compositing a candle and I want apply some effect to only the flame. So I activated the  *Emit* pass so it will only be affected, and I applied some glare effects to it.
My question is how can I combine this *Emit* pass with the rest of the image? Secondly what is the correct order of the glaring nodes I mean by types fog, ghosts, ect?
[image: compostier]

Comment: for a case like yours I would use a color operation such as *Screen* or *Lighten*.  A good read about [blend modes](http://www.cgtextures.com/content.php?action=tutorial&name=blendmodes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use *add* here.
When you set the glare nodes to a mix of 1, then they only output the glare, without the original image.

As for the order of the glare nodes, I would apply them all at once.
By applying them one after the other, the next one includes the effect of the previous one in it's calculation, making the result brighter than it should be (and potentially doing things like putting starbursts on the ghost images..).

Instead apply then all to the same source with a mix of 1, then add them together:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fix the 1st problem by multiplying the mask of the flames by the original image then add the filtered flames so it will be added to a 0 pixels.but still dont know the 2nd question

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution is to use Color -> Mix node, set it to add. Plug in the composite image, plus the filtered image. Output it to the viewer and composite output.

Comment: but this give me a very bright white color in the flames

Comment: You should use Screen for this.